# Unable to read more than 7 pages of docx to String using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

I am trying to read the content of docx file to string using Apache POI. Im able to read the contents but when the number of pages in docx is more than 7 0r 8, the contents from the 8th page is displayed before the first 7 pages. we are using following code:

```
File doc=new File("D:\\1.docx");
        InputStream repoDocument = new FileInputStream(doc);
        XWPFDocument document=new XWPFDocument(repoDocument);

    XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document) ;
    String content =  extractor.getText();
    content = content.replace(" ", "");
    System.out.println(content);
```

can anyone help us in fixing this..?

Comment: What kind of word documents are you processing? is there anything special concerning used formattings? Have you just tried using a word document that is repeating the same word over and over?

Comment: The document contains text and tables with images in the header and footer. But we need to read only content in the text and table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is tagged docx4j, I take it you are also interested in how you'd solve this problem that way.

It is done using [org.docx4j.TextUtils](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/TextUtils.java)

Here's a demo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String inputfilepath = "YOUR_PATH/YOUR.docx";

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
    MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();        

    org.docx4j.wml.Document wmlDocumentEl = (org.docx4j.wml.Document)documentPart.getJaxbElement();

    Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);

    org.docx4j.TextUtils.extractText(wmlDocumentEl, out);

    out.close();

}
```